# Node Object - Assign value for a null Node object

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I was parsing a XMl file and using the contents for processing a data setup in java using XPath, There may be situation that we can get empty tags as input which should be processed.

But when i tried to set value for the null node object with **setNodeValue** and **setTextContent** methods still getting the same issue. Do we have any other option to set value for null Node object.

```
    **//Code Snippet:**
Node title = XPathAPI.selectSingleNode("Input Node", "title/text()");
// *Here if there is no input title tag, then the title variable would be null*
title.setNodeValue("Value to set on the null node");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `title` is `null` then you can't call a method on it. That would result in a NullPointerException. You need to create and add a new node first and then call `setNodeValue` on the new node. E.g.

```
// your xml document
Document document = ...;

// create a new node to add
Node titleNode = document.createElement("title");
titleNode.setNodeValue("Value to set on the null node");

// The node named "Input Node" in document
Node inputNode = ...;

// append the new node to "Input Node"
inputNode.appendChild(titleNode);
```